# Find $\mathbb P(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n \} >y), y \in \mathbb R$, $X_i$ iid

Tags: probability, statistics

Find $\mathbb P(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} > y), \: \: y\in \mathbb R$ where $X_i$ are iid with pdf
\begin{align}
    f(y) &=
    \begin{cases}
        \lambda y^{-2}, & y \geq \lambda\\
        0, & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\lambda >0$

**Attempt:**
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} > y) 
&= \mathbb P(X_1>y,\ldots,X_n>y)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb P(X_i>y)\\
&= \left(\int_y^\infty \lambda x^{-2} dx\right)^n
\end{align}
**is this the right approach, in particular the last line?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathbf{P}(X \in E) = \int_E f$ where $f$ is the pdf of $X$. In this case, $E = (y,\infty)$ and

$$ \int_{(y,\infty)} f = \int_y^\infty f = \int_y^\infty f(x)\,dx. $$

The rest of your solution is also correct.

Just one thing to pay attention to: the probability is $1$ if $y < \lambda$ and otherwise it is given by $\left( \int_{y}^\infty \lambda x^{-2} \,dx \right)^n$.

Comment: thanks for the response! did you mean to say 'the prob is 0 if $y<\lambda$'?

Comment: @veritas No, he meant what he said. This is related to an error in your solution: Where you write $\int_y^\infty \lambda x^{-2} dx$ you should have $\int_y^\infty f(x)\,dx$ instead. That's the same thing if $y\ge\lambda$  but not the same thing if $y<\lambda$.

Comment: can you please explain further why the prob is 1 if $y< \lambda$? i don't quite understand

Comment: actually I had a good think about it. I'm quite sure I get it now. I will edit in an explanation for future reference.